# WPF Databinding, no clue why it isn't working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, textblock

I have successfully bound window items to view models before using wpf data binding, almost, the exact same way as I'm doing here.

I have a GUI with the XAML for my TextBlock binding to change the colour and text with the system state;

```
<TextBlock 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,359,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    Text="{Binding Path=StateText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="565" Height="84" 
    Background="{Binding Path=StateColour, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I set the datacontext to my view model in my xaml.cs;

```
MobilityWelcomeViewModel mobilityWelcomeViewModel = new mobilityWelcomeViewModel();

public MobilityWelcome()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this.mobilityWelcomeViewModel;
}
```

I have this constructor which writes to my data model via the specified adapter;

```
public class MobilityWelcomeViewModel
{
    private bool State;
    private string _Text;
    private Brush _StateColour;
    BackgroundWorker StateWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
}

public ShellEMobilityWelcomeViewModel()
{
    this._ANMStateColour = Brushes.White;
    this.ANMStateWorker.DoWork += this.ANMStateWorker_DoWork;
    this.ANMStateWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += this.ANMStateWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    this.ANMStateWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    this._ANMText = "Loading ANM State";

    IApplicationPointAdapter testWrite = AdapterFactory.Instance.GetApplicationPointAdapter();
        testWrite.WriteBinary("HMI.EV.SITE1.STATUS.CONTACTBREAKEROPEN", false);

}
```

In my view model I have the properties;

```
public Brush StateColour
{
    get { return this._StateColour; }
    set { this._StateColour = value; }
}

public string StateText
{
    get { return this._Text; }
    set { }
}
```

I have background workers which I can see change these values in debug.

I'm really stumped here. The whole binding thing seems pretty simple at surface so, from my fairly new and probably naive, knowledge of it I can't see what I've done wrong.

Thanks in advance. (also i've changed the variable names to disguise my project so if there is a spelling disparoty between like objects or likewise just ignore it)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting the datacontext but not initialising your ViewModel in the right place.

Just to double check you can use tools like Snoop to see what is going wrong.

You should be initialising your ViewModel in the contructor

like below.

```
public MobilityWelcome()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mobilityWelcomeViewModel = new mobilityWelcomeViewModel();
        this.DataContext = this.mobilityWelcomeViewModel;
    }
```

Also make sure you are implementing INotificationPropertyChanged.

Your property setters should be like below

```
public Brush StateColour
    {
        get { return this._StateColour; }
        set { this._StateColour = value; 
              OnPropertyChanged("StateColour");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I implemented the interface and moved the instantiation to the constructor. However, there was no effect. Although I tried using a textbox instead of a text block and that works with the view model parameters being altered remotely. Although only the text will change with the view model, the brush will not

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure if I understand your problem fully. But I created a sample project with a Brush as a property and it updates the background of a textblock when I change it in the viewmodel. One thing I say is you are trying to change the color of the private property in this line this._ANMStateColour = Brushes.White; Can you change that to public property please. like ANMSTateColour = Brushes.White, because a private property does not fire OnPropertyChanged even to let the UI know that its value has been changed

Comment: I found a fix! My using statement was importing the wrong type of brush. I changed using System.Windows.Drawing to using System.Windows.Media

Comment: @Krishna "a private property does not fire OnPropertyChanged" is not true. If it fires a change notification or not depends entirely on the implementation of the setter method. Perhaps you mean that a private property can't be used as the source of a binding.

Comment: @MarkCorrigan You should typically not use any WinForms stuff in a WPF application. Remove the reference to the System.Drawing assembly from your project.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the clarification, sorry I meant a private property cannot be used in the binding in the xaml so a public property must be changed in the viewmodel in order to reflect those changes in the ui.